# How do I change android.permission settings when running tests

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin

### Question

I'm working on a third party library that uses geolocation if the 1st party library has provided permissions. I would like to test the behavior, but cannot ship my app w/ the permissions set in the manifest (b/c then it wouldn't be optional).

Is there anyway to set e.g., `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` only while I'm running tests?

### Details

I'm using the gradle build tools `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2` and have followed the androidTest directory convention. My project looks like this:

`tree src -L 3
src
├── androidTest
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   └── resources
└── main
    ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    └── java
        └── com`

I tried adding a second manifest in the androidTest folder (I updated the package to be: package="com.myapp.test"), but the geo permissions do not take effect.

I've considered switching to robolectric, but would rather just use the Instrumentation test short term. Please advise if that will make this much easier though.

Answer (score 4):

I found a decent solution (not the cleanest IMO):

Add this to your `<appname>/build.gradle`:

```groovy
android {
  ...
  sourceSets {
    debug {
      manifest.srcFile 'src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And then, of course, create an *AndroidManifest.xml* file in `src/androidTest/` with your required permissions.
I snagged this from the [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74379).

Comment: I haven't had time to test yet. (I appreciate the answer, but I'm swamped.) I'll try it this week.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work. The manifest is taken automagically when running android tests, which prevented me from overriding the manifest. I do think something along these lines should work. Maybe there's more I should be doing here.

Comment: Hmm... maybe setting sourceSets.debug to sourceSets.androidTest instead would fix it...

Comment: I tried configuring various source sets. I think this might just be a limitation of Android at the moment.