# How to Add Permissions to AndroidManifest.xml for Tests

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-testing

The [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration) state:

> As mentioned previously, next to the main sourceSet is the androidTest sourceSet, located by default in src/androidTest/
>   ....
>   **The sourceSet should not contain an AndroidManifest.xml as it is automatically generated.**

So, if I want to add extra permissions for the tests, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276537/how-do-i-change-android-permission-settings-when-running-tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 0.13.0 (released 2014/09/18) of the Android Gradle plugin it is now possible to have a custom manifest for Android tests.

> It is now possible to provide a manifest for test apps (src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml)

Source: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system

For more information see the sample ["gradle_examples_0.14.4/tree/master/androidManifestInTest"](https://github.com/snooplsm/gradle_examples_0.14.4/tree/master/androidManifestInTest) - although it seems to me that there's no special configuration needed.

Comment: Note that depending on your project structure and `build.gradle` this might now work and only use/merge the AndroidManifest.xml in `src/debug`.